# Jasmine test to verify that a callback does not raise an error

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, jasmine, typeerror

How do I write a Jasmine test to verify that an asynchronous callback does *not* raise an error?

I am writing a function with this basic pattern:

```
myFunction: function (callback) {
   this.doSomethingAsync(function () {
      if (callback) {
          callback();
      }
    });
    return "done";
 }
```

The parameter `callback` is optional.  Thus, the `if` statement skips the callback if the user doesn't supply one.

I want to write a Jasmine test that will fail if somebody removes the `if` statement in the future.  However, I can't think of how to structure the test.

The consequence of removing the `if` statement and calling `myFunction` is that Javascript raises this `TypeError`:

```
Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function
```

However, I can't think of how to set up a Jasmine test to verify that no such error is raised.

Comment: @GaryHayes, what? The variable being passed in to the function *is* the function he is trying to call.

Comment: He's taking a function as a parameter, `callback`, and checking that it exists before calling it.  If he removes the `if (callback)` and still calls the function but the caller didn't pass a function as the parameter, he will get the error `callback is not a function`.  He's doing it right, just looking for a way to write a test around it.

Comment: But why the concern for what someone may do in the future to break it? That is on the future person to figure out. The code works as is.

Comment: That's part of the point of unit tests...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you could serialize the async part by mocking related functions to **execute synchroneously**. Then you can test the expected behaviour by using the `.not.toThrow()` expectation.

Assuming this demo object:

```
var objUnderTest = {

    doSomethingAsync: function(fn) {
        console.info("Doing something async.");

        setTimeout(function(){
            console.info("Done something async.");
            fn();
        }, 1000);
    },

    myFunction: function(callback) {
        this.doSomethingAsync(function() {
            if (callback) {
                callback();
            }
        });

        return "done";
    }
};
```

Your test could look like this:

```
describe("Test", function(){
    beforeEach(function(){
        // serialize calls for easier testing
        // now your closure passed to doSomethingAsync() will directly be called
        spyOn(objUnderTest, "doSomethingAsync").and.callFake(function(fn){
            fn();
        });
    });

    it("should call the callback on myFunction(<callack>)", function() {
        var callback = jasmine.createSpy("callback");
        objUnderTest.myFunction(callback);
        expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it("should not throw on myFunction() without callback", function(){
        expect(function(){
            objUnderTest.myFunction();
        }).not.toThrow();
    });
});
```

Since you only want to test that your `myFunction` behaves correctly, I think it's fine to mock `doSomethingAsync` even if it's part of the module-under-test.

If you don't want to mock a method in the object under test, you could mock away all methods called by the `doSomethingAsync()` method.

Assuming the demo object you would need to mock `setTimeout()`:

```
spyOn(window, "setTimeout").and.callFake(function(fn){
    fn();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can stub out the doSomethingAsync function, and have it only call the callback function

```
describe('doSomthingAsync', function(){
  function A(){
    this.doSomethingAsync = function(cb){
      setTimeout(function(){
        cb();
      },2000);
    }
    this.myFunction = function(cb){
      this.doSomethingAsync(function(){
          cb();
      })
    }
  }

  it('tests for the throws', function(){
    var a = new A();
    a.doSomethingAsync = function(cb){
      cb();
    }

    var func = function(){
      a.myFunction();
    };

    var func2 = function(){
      a.myFunction(function(){
        console.log('ping');
      });
    }

    expect(func).toThrow(Error);
    expect(func2).not.toThrow(Error);
  });
});
```

Though, I'd probably enforce the fact that the callback is optional by putting the code to check if the callback is defined elsewhere.

```
...
this.doSomethingAsync = function(cb){
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(cb && typeof cb === 'function'){
            cb();
        }
        //do other stuff
    }, 2000)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  It took me a minute to understand your example above; but, in my opinion, the key idea is that the doSomethingAsync stub is actually synchronous for this test.  Also, because I'm not looking for a specific type of error, I think the last line should be expect(func2).not.toThrow().

Comment: @Zack you're correct, making the doSomethingAsync stub synchronous was a great help. however Jasmine does have something called `done` that can be used to indicate when a test finished. The main point of my stub here was to get rid of the stuff we don't care about. For the test we don't care about what doSomethingAsync does, we only care if it will throw an error when calling the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem when making karma-jasmine tests to check that my library throws an exception if proper init does not happen until timeout. While there is an option to provide your own `setTimeout`, I wanted to leave test as close as possible to prod conditions. I settled for this

```
//...some code that sets up eventual failure
var oldOnError = window.onerror;
var thrownMessage: string;
window.onerror = function(msg){
    thrownMessage = msg;
}

window.setTimeout(function(){
  window.onerror = oldOnError;
  expect(thrownMessage).toBeDefined();
  expect(thrownMessage.indexOf("unresolved") > -1).toBe(true);
  done();
}, 100);
```

In node you can probably use this (haven't tested it though)

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  expect(....);
  done();
})
```